# How to add defer attribute to :javascript in Haml

Tags: javascript, haml

Is there a way to include the `defer` (or `async`) attribute to the `:javascript` section of a Haml file, something in the likes of:

```
%body
  %div
    etc etc

:javascript{defer: true}
  $(document).ready(function() {
    // whatever JS code
  });
```